# TYPO3 how to extend HTML main layout

Tags: php, html, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I looked for a way to make children pages ineherit parent plugin

I found this that works to the inheritance but in place of get the plugin on the main content zone of the pages, it took all the page.

How could I change the typoscript config to take only the content div and not the whole page.

The actual configuration

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = USER
page.10 {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    vendorName = LUSIS
    extensionName = JurisprudenceLegislation
    pluginName = JurisprudenceLegislation
    switchableControllerActions {
        Frontend {
            0 = routing
        }
    }
}
```

The typoscript of the template

```
config.baseURL = {$siteURL}
config.tx_realurl_enable = 1

page {
    meta.keywords.data = register:newsKeywords // field : keywords
    meta.description.data = register:newsSubheader // field : description
}



##############################################################
# This is TypoScript used to modify the core templates to
# display this skin. Rewrite the header, footer, pre code and 
# post code libraries and more when needed to change structure
##############################################################

preCodeHeader = TEXT
preCodeHeader.value = <div id="pageWrap">
postCodeHeader >

preCodeFeature >
postCodeFeature >

preCodeContent = TEXT
preCodeContent.value (
    <div id="content">
)

preCodeGeneratedContent-1 >
postCodeGeneratedContent-1 >

preCodeContentBlock-1 = TEXT
preCodeContentBlock-1.value = <a href="#beginContent" id="beginContent" class="outOfSight" name="beginContent"></a>
postCodeContentBlock-1 >

preCodeContentBlock-2 >
postCodeContentBlock-2 >

preCodeContentBlock-3 >
postCodeContentBlock-3 >

preCodeGeneratedContent-2 >
postCodeGeneratedContent-2 >

preCodeFooter  = TEXT
preCodeFooter.value (

    </div>
    <!-- end #content  -->
)
postCodeFooter = TEXT
postCodeFooter.value (

    </div>
    <!-- end #pageWrap  -->
)



### Lets table classes be added in the RTE
lib.parseFunc_RTE.externalBlocks.table.stdWrap.HTMLparser.tags.table.fixAttrib.class.list >
lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines.addAttributes.P.class >

### Menu de support niveau 1
### Normalement tout est customisable via CSS

globalMenu >
globalMenu = HMENU
globalMenu.special = directory
globalMenu.special.value = {$globalMenuPageId}
globalMenu.wrap = <ul id="globalMenu">|</ul><div class="clearOnly">&nbsp;</div><!-- end #globalMenu  -->
globalMenu.1 = TMENU
globalMenu.1 {
    noBlur = 1
    NO.subst_elementUid = 1
    NO.before = <li id="globalMenuItem-{elementUid}">|*|<li id="globalMenuItem-{elementUid}">|*|<li id="globalMenuItem-{elementUid}" class="last">
    NO.after = </li>
    NO.stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
    ACT = 1
    ACT.subst_elementUid = 1
    ACT.before = <li id="globalMenuItem-{elementUid}" class="active">|*|<li id="globalMenuItem-{elementUid}" class="active">|*|<li id="globalMenuItem-{elementUid}" class="active last">
    ACT.after = </li>
    ACT.stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
}

#### Fils d'Ariane

breadcrumb >
breadcrumb=COA
breadcrumb {
10 = HMENU
10 {
 special = rootline
 special.range = 0|-1
 # "not in menu pages" should show up in the breadcrumbs menu
 includeNotInMenu = 0
 1 = TMENU
     # no unneccessary scripting.
     1.noBlur = 1
     # Current item should be unlinked
     1.CUR = 1
     1.target = _self
     1.wrap = <div class="breadcrumb"> | </div>
     1.NO {
         stdWrap.field = title
         ATagTitle.field = nav_title // title
         linkWrap = ||*|  <span class="separator"> &gt;</span> |*|
         }
     # Current menu item is unlinked
     1.CUR {
         stdWrap.field = title
         linkWrap = ||*|   <span class="separator"> &gt;</span> <span class="current">|</span>|
         doNotLinkIt = 1
         }
    }
}

### Sous-rubriques

subFolder >
subFolder = HMENU
subFolder.special = directory
subFolder.stdWrap.required=1
subFolder.stdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="clearOnly">&nbsp;</div><div id="subFolderBox"><div class="subFolderTitle"><span>Sous-Rubriques</span></div><div class="subFolderContent"><div class="contentTop"><ul id="subFolder">|</ul></div><div class="contentBottom"><div class="contentLeft"></div><div class="contentRight"></div></div></div></div><!-- end #subFolderBox  -->
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
subFolder.stdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="clearOnly">&nbsp;</div><div id="subFolderBox"><div class="subFolderTitle"><span>Sub-Folders</span></div><div class="subFolderContent"><div class="contentTop"><ul id="subFolder">|</ul></div><div class="contentBottom"><div class="contentLeft"></div><div class="contentRight"></div></div></div></div><!-- end #subFolderBox  -->
[GLOBAL]
subFolder.1 = TMENU
subFolder.1 {
    noBlur = 1
    NO.subst_elementUid = 1
    NO.before = <li>|*|<li>|*|<li class="last">
    NO.after = </li>
    NO.stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
}



## Menu de langue
langMenu >
langMenu = HMENU
langMenu.wrap= <div id="langMenu">|</div>
langMenu.special = language
langMenu.special.value = 0,1,2,5
langMenu.1 = GMENU
langMenu.1.NO {
  XY = [5.w]+6, [5.h]+5
  backColor = white
  transparentColor=white
  5 = IMAGE
  5.file = fileadmin/flags/flag_fr.gif  || fileadmin/flags/flag_uk.gif  || fileadmin/flags/flag_de.gif  || fileadmin/flags/hl_pt.gif
  5.offset = 3,3
}

langMenu.1.ACT < langMenu.1.NO
langMenu.1.ACT=1
langMenu.1.ACT.backColor = #1B4B7A

langMenu.1.USERDEF1 < langMenu.1.NO
langMenu.1.USERDEF1=1
langMenu.1.USERDEF1.5.file = fileadmin/flags/flag_fr_d.gif  || fileadmin/flags/flag_uk_d.gif  || fileadmin/flags/flag_de_d.gif || fileadmin/flags/flag_pt_d.gif 
langMenu.1.USERDEF1.noLink = 1

langMenu.1.USERDEF2 < langMenu.1.NO
langMenu.1.USERDEF2=1
langMenu.1.USERDEF2.5.file = fileadmin/flags/flag_fr_d.gif  || fileadmin/flags/flag_uk_d.gif  || fileadmin/flags/flag_de_d.gif || fileadmin/flags/flag_pt_d.gif 
langMenu.1.USERDEF2.noLink = 1
langMenu.1.USERDEF2.backColor = #1B4B7A

## Configuration de langue

##ParamÃƒÂ¨tres de langues

# Langue par defaut
config.sys_language_uid = 0
config.language = fr
config.locale_all = fr_FR
config.htmlTag_langKey = fr
config.linkVars = L

config.sys_language_mode = content_fallback
config.sys_language_overlay = 1
// Liste des langues via le language switcher

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
config.sys_language_uid = 1
config.language = en
config.locale_all = en_US
config.htmlTag_langKey = en
[GLOBAL]

[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
config.sys_language_uid = 2
config.language = de
config.locale_all = de_DE
config.htmlTag_langKey = de
[GLOBAL]

[globalVar = GP:L = 5]
config.sys_language_uid = 5
config.language = pt
config.locale_all = pt_PT
config.htmlTag_langKey = pt
[GLOBAL]


## Menu de support niveau 2
topMenu >
topMenu = HMENU
topMenu.special = directory
topMenu.special.value = {$topMenuPageId}
topMenu.wrap = <ul id="topMenu">|</ul><!-- end #topMenu  -->
topMenu.1 = TMENU
topMenu.1 {
    noBlur = 1
    NO.subst_elementUid = 1
    NO.before = <li id="topMenuItem-{elementUid}">|*|<li id="topMenuItem-{elementUid}">|*|<li id="topMenuItem-{elementUid}" class="last">
    NO.after = </li>
    NO.stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
    ACT = 1
    ACT.subst_elementUid = 1
    ACT.before = <li id="topMenuItem-{elementUid}" class="active">|*|<li id="topMenuItem-{elementUid}" class="active">|*|<li id="topMenuItem-{elementUid}" class="active last">
    ACT.after = </li>
    ACT.stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
}


# --- Recherche ----------------------------------
## Configuration gÃƒÂ©nÃƒÂ©rale
config.index_enable = 1
config.index_externals = 1
config.redirectOldLinksToNew = 0

## Box de recherche
plugin.tx_macinasearchbox_pi1 {
    pidSearchpage = {$searchPageId}
    templateFile = {$templavoila_framework.skinPath}ext-templates/indexed-search/template.htm
}

## Configuration page de recherche/recherche avancÃƒÂ©e
plugin.tx_indexedsearch {
 templateFile={$templavoila_framework.skinPath}ext-templates/indexed-search/indexed-search.tmpl
 search.exactCount = 0
 blind {
    type=0
    defOp=0
    sections=0
    media=0
    order=0
    group=0
    extResume = 0
    lang=0
    desc=0
    results=0
    type {
        10 = 1 // on cache le type PhonÃƒÂ©tique
    }
    sections {
        -1 = 1
        -2 = 1
        -3 = 1
    }
 }
 show {
    rules=0
    advancedSearchLink = 1
    resultNumber = 1 
    rootPidList = -1 
    parsetimes=1
    L2sections=1
    L1sections=1
    LxALLtypes=0
 }
}

// Exemple de traduction de libellÃƒÂ© de la recherche avancÃƒÂ©e
// plugin.tx_indexedsearch._LOCAL_LANG.fr.rules_header = RÃƒÂ¨gles
plugin.tx_indexedsearch._LOCAL_LANG.fr.form_from = PÃƒÂ©riode de recherche :
plugin.tx_indexedsearch._LOCAL_LANG.fr.form_to = A :

plugin.tx_indexedsearch._LOCAL_LANG.en.form_from = From :
plugin.tx_indexedsearch._LOCAL_LANG.en.form_to = To :

## Header global : Reprend les ÃƒÂ©lÃƒÂ©ments prÃƒÂ©cÃƒÂ©dents

header >
header = COA
header.wrap = <div id="header"> | </div>
header.10 = COA
header.10.wrap = <div id="hdr"><div id="logo-site"><a href="{$siteURL}" title="home"><img src="{$siteLogo}" alt="logo"/></a></div> | </div>
header.10.20.wrap = <div id="support-menu"> | <div id="cornersupport"></div><div class="clearOnly">&nbsp;</div></div>
header.10.20 = COA
header.10.20.10 < {$langMenu}
header.10.20.20 < topMenu

# --- SEARCHBOX OBJECT ----------------------------------
lib.searchbox = COA_INT
lib.searchbox {
  stdWrap.prefixComment = 2 | lib.searchbox
  10 = TEXT
  10.typolink.parameter = {$searchPageId}
  10.typolink.returnLast = url
  10.wrap = <div class="tx-macinasearchbox-pi1"><form action="|" method="post" id="indexedsearch">Recherche :&nbsp;

  20 = COA
  20 {
    10 = TEXT
    10.data = GPvar : tx_indexedsearch |sword
    10.htmlSpecialChars = 1
    10.wrap = <input name="tx_indexedsearch[sword]" value="|" class="searchBoxInput" type="text" />
    20 = COA
    20 {
      10 = TEXT
      10.value = <input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[sections]" value="0" /><input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[pointer]" value="0" /><input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[ext]" value="0" />
      15 = TEXT
      15.value = <input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[lang]" value="0" />
      20 = TEXT
      20.value = <input name="tx_indexedsearch[submit_button]"  type="submit" class="searchBoxSubmit" value="OK" />
    }
  }
  30 = COA
  30 {
    10 = TEXT
    10.value = Recherche avancÃ©e

    10.typolink.parameter = {$searchPageId}
    10.typolink.additionalParams = &tx_indexedsearch[ext]=1
    10.wrap = <span id="advancedsearch" class="button_mid_ico">|</span>
  ##  if.isTrue = {$plugin.tx_indexedsearch.showAdvanced}
  }
  wrap = | </form></div>
}

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
lib.searchbox.10.wrap = <div class="tx-macinasearchbox-pi1"><form action="|" method="post" id="indexedsearch">Search :&nbsp;
lib.searchbox.30.10.value = Advanced Search
lib.searchbox.20.20.15.value = <input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[lang]" value="1" />
[global]
// CORRECTION
header.20 = COA
header.20.wrap = <div id="search"><div class="contentLeft"></div><div class="contentRight"></div> | </div>
#header.20.10 < plugin.tx_macinasearchbox_pi1
header.20.10 < lib.searchbox
// FIN CORRECTION




header.30 = COA
header.30.wrap = <div id="main-menu"><div class="contentLeft"></div><div class="contentRight"></div> | </div>
header.30.10 < globalMenu

## Header spÃƒÂ©cifique ÃƒÂ  la Newsletter
headerNewsletter >
headerNewsletter = COA
headerNewsletter.wrap = <div id="hdrNewsletter"> | </div>

## Fotter
footer >

footer = TEXT
footer {
    data = date:U
    strftime = %Y
    dataWrap = <div class="clearOnly">&nbsp;</div><div id="footer" class="clear"><p id="footerCopyright">&copy;&nbsp; | &nbsp;{$copyright}</p><div class="clearOnly">&nbsp;</div></div><!-- end #footer  -->
}

## Javascript si le site contient la librairie JQuery

[globalVar = LIT:1 = {$enableJQuery}]
## Javascript + CSS
page {
    includeCSS {
        tf_skin_z1 = {$templavoila_framework.skinPath}css/custom-theme/jquery-ui.min.css
        tf_skin_z3 = {$templavoila_framework.skinPath}css/treeview/jquery.treeview.css
        tf_skin_z4 = {$templavoila_framework.skinPath}css/print.css
        tf_skin_z5 = {$templavoila_framework.skinPath}css/powermail/powermail-custom.css
        tf_skin_z4.title = Print CSS
        tf_skin_z4.media = print
    }
    includeJS {
        tf_skin_z1 = {$templavoila_framework.skinPath}js/jquery-ui.min.js
        tf_skin_z2 = {$templavoila_framework.skinPath}js/jquery.treeview.min.js
        tf_skin_z3 = {$templavoila_framework.skinPath}js/jquery.cookie.js
    }
}
[global]
```

Sorry but I'm almost beginner in typoscript syntax

Answer (score 0):

You should define a (HTML-)templating for your pages.
I would prefer FLUID as state of the art.
Then you would define your content in some fluid variables and your inherited content could be one of these.

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
    templateName = Default
    layoutRootPaths {
        10 = EXT:my_site_ext/Resources/Private/Layouts
    }
    partialRootPaths {
        10 = EXT:my_site_ext/Resources/Private/Partials
    }
    templateRootPaths {
        10 = EXT:my_site_ext/Resources/Private/Templates
    }
    variables {
        content < styles.content.get
        contentLeft < styles.content.get
        contentLeft.select.where = colPos = 1

        contentRight = USER
        contentRight {
            userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
            vendorName = LUSIS
            extensionName = JurisprudenceLegislation
            pluginName = JurisprudenceLegislation
            switchableControllerActions {
                Frontend {
                    0 = routing
                }
            }
        }

        footer < lib.footer
        :
    }
}
```

Try to use `lib.anything` or even better `temp.anything` for all content you predefine and copy afterwards into the fluid variables.
And so you can use `lib.anything` from fluid prefer variables which are set in the beginning of the fluid working.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i will try it